# Save the data with a hierarchical key or replicate the data in a DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in dynamodb with hierarchical information, example agency A -> agency B -> agency C, etc.
In another table I need to keep data related to this hierarchy of agencies, this data has general information of all agencies and other information specific to each agency.
For example, if the item is created by agency C, it should be seen in agency C, agency B and agency A, if it is created by agency B in agency B and agency A and if it is created agency A, only agency A. should see it. have several levels.
I was thinking two ways of doing this:
1. Replicate the same element for each level of agency and use an index with PK id of the agency, in this way I can obtain the respective elements of each agency.
2. Create a single element with a global index PK 'ELEMENT' and SK agencyAId # agencyBId # agencyCId, etc and be able to search the elements of an agency using PK -> 'ELEMENT' and SK -> startWith (agencyAId # agencyBId # agencyCId, etc)

What will be the best way ?, the first creates a large amount of redundant data and when creating or updating an element if a failure occurs it would be difficult to maintain integrity.
and in the second a hot partition would be created.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: go with duplication/sql instead of hot keys, since the only gain of nosql is performance, if you have hot key and getting data in O(n), it does not make sense to go the nosql path anyway.